# Finding middle of user input (int) and increasing/decreasing half of the values in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Im trying to implement a program in Java that a user inputs a number greater than 10 & another number (whatever number) then it will list whatever first number the user inputs for example if it was 11 then it'd print 1-11 with corresponding numbers in which it increases by 50 in the first half (1-6) and decreases 25 for the rest (7-11). I have the following code but im having trouble trying to figure out the logic/how to go about the values being increased/decreased.

again the output would be something like this:

1 550
2 600
3 650
4 700
5 750
6 800
7 775
8 750
9 725
10 700
11 675

```
import java.util.Scanner; 


public class Periods2
{   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("enter the number of days in a given period:");
    int numbers = 1;

   int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

   if(number < 10){
  System.out.print("the number of days doesnt meet the required criteria enter it again:");
  number = reader.nextInt();

   }

    System.out.print("enter the number of sharepoints:");
   int sharepoints = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());



    while (numbers <= number && sharepoints > number){ 
        System.out.println(numbers + "  " + sharepoints);
        numbers++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Keep in mind that SO is not for "Why is this code not working" questions.

Comment: "*Increases by 50 everyday in the first half (1-6) and decreases for the rest (7-11)*" decreases for how much? `25`?

Comment: @Taelsin my question is how would I get half of the users input and increase the first half & decrease the second half

Comment: @Fureeish whoops didn't see that I left that out yes 25 ! Thanks for pointing that out I have edited.

Comment: what is the sharepoints input? 500?

Comment: @roshan in this example 11 is the number > 10 & 550 is the sharepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the half of your input, and in your loop you can add 50 to sharepoints until the value of numbers reaches half, and then decrease by 25 after that:

```
int half = (int) Math.ceil(number/2.0);


while (numbers <= number && sharepoints > number){ 

    System.out.println(numbers + "  " + sharepoints);

    if(numbers < half) {
    sharepoints += 50;    
    }
    else {
    sharepoints -= 25;    
    }
    numbers++;
}
```